# Can compiz be installed on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, compiz

I always used Compiz with Debian,

Does it work correctly with Ubuntu 11.10?

If yes, what is the command that I need use to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Compiz as its default window manager, so it should already be installed.

If you want to customize its behaviour, launch the Ubuntu Software Center and install the

**CompizConfig Settings Manager** ("ccsm", if you prefer install it from apt-get).

Comment: Interesting I didn't knew that, I thought it was like Debian that use Metacity as default window manager.

Comment: Actually, @Zignd, Metacity is a Gtk2 window manager. Gnome Shell (which Debian Wheezy and Sid use) is based on Mutter.